# I haven't already covered vs. I haven't covered yet

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the difference between these two pertaining an activity that is not covered or already covered.

> I believe I haven't **already** covered this global warming topic. (Teacher)

Vs.

> I believe I haven't covered this global warming topic **yet**. (Teacher)

Is there any difference? Such as the time it played out or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 'already' is used with negation, it most likely emphasizes that something should have happened by the moment.

'Not yet' is a neutral expression for something expected to happen soon.

> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/already-still-or-yet
>
> (*Negatives with already are far less common than negatives with
>   yet... They usually refer to things which should have happened before
>   they did happen*)

So in your first example the teacher probably planned to cover that topic by the moment, in the second one the time for the teacher's explanation has not come yet.